# Getting the values calculated by stat_summary with mean_cl_boot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, mean, confidence-interval

I'm plotting some X values with `mean_cl_boot` with large confidence intervals

How can I export the text for both the value of the `fun.y = mean` and `fun.data = mean_cl_boot` in each group?

I have an interval of values in `mean_cl_boot`, and I would like to plot them and export them.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) + 
geom_jitter(width = 0.5) + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", color = "red") + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, fun.args=(conf.int=0.9999), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4)
```

I got to plot the mean (`fun.y = mean`) value, with:

```
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)),size=3, show.legend=FALSE
```

But I can't to the same with `mean_cl_boot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get access to the data of `stat_summary` with `ggplot_build`.

First, store your ggplot call in an object:

```
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.5) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", color = "red") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, fun.args=(conf.int=0.9999), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4)
```

Then, with:

```
ggplot_build(g)$data[[3]]
```

You get the values calculated with `mean_cl_boot`:

> ```
>   x group     y     ymin     ymax PANEL xmin xmax colour size linetype width alpha
> 1 1     1 1.462 1.386000 1.543501     1  0.8  1.2  black  0.5        1   0.4    NA
> 2 2     2 4.260 4.024899 4.462202     1  1.8  2.2  black  0.5        1   0.4    NA
> 3 3     3 5.552 5.337199 5.798202     1  2.8  3.2  black  0.5        1   0.4    NA
> ```

---

For getting the labels right, you could do:

```
# extract the data
mcb <- ggplot_build(g)$data[[3]]

# add the labels to the plot
g + geom_text(data = mcb,
              aes(x = group, y = ymin, label = round(ymin,2)),
              color = "blue",
              vjust = 1)
```

the result:

[image]

But probably an even better alternative is using the [ggrepel](/questions/tagged/ggrepel) package:

```
library(ggrepel)

g + geom_label_repel(data = mcb,
                     aes(x = group, y = ymin, label = round(ymin,2)),
                     color = "blue",
                     nudge_x = 0.2,
                     nudge_y = -0.2)
```

the result of that:

[image]

Comment: I observed that by using:                                                                 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, fun.args=(conf.int=0.9999), geom = "text", aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..ymin..)), width = 0.4)  or ymax                                                                   I can plot ymax and ymin, but with no defined location on the graph. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @GabrielG. What do you mean with *defined location*?

Comment: For example, the min right under the error bar and the max above the error bar. If I use vjust within the code above, I don't get perfect matching on aligment!

Comment: Very nice touch to the graph. Thank you very much!